# Implement a complex Flutter Timeline widget

Tags: flutter

[image]how to implement this complex flutter timeline?

i tried to use [this code](https://petercoding.com/flutter/2021/06/24/creating-a-timeline-component-in-flutter/)

Comment: then  what  errors comes in  the  code

Comment: no errors  , but pick ups must be a list widget, same thing with drop offs

Answer (score 2):

This [pub package](https://pub.dev/packages/timelines) likely fits your usecase. It includes code to create timelines as you specified.